# VBA cant copy and paste cell with single value

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code that loop through excel files in a folder and copy the value and paste them to a new workbook.

The problem occur when I have files that only have a single value in the cell. It return an error stating

> copy area and paste area aren't the same size

Below is my code:

```
Sub MergeDataFromWorkbooks()
    'DECLARE AND SET VARIABLES
    Dim wbk As Workbook
    Dim wbk1 As Workbook
    Set wbk1 = ThisWorkbook

    Dim Filename As String
    Dim Path As String
    Path = "C:\Users\Desktop\merge all to one\" 'CHANGE PATH ACCORDING TO FOLDER DIRECTORY LEAVING \ AT THE END
    Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xlsx")

    '--------------------------------------------
    'OPEN EXCEL FILES
    Do While Len(Filename) > 0 'IF NEXT FILE EXISTS THEN
        Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(Path & Filename)
        wbk.Activate
        Range("A2").Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Windows("Book1.xlsm").Activate
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False

        Dim lr As Double
        lr = wbk1.Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        Sheets(1).Select
        Cells(lr + 1, 1).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        wbk.Close True
        Filename = Dir
    Loop

    MsgBox "All the files are copied and pasted in Book1."
End Sub
```

[image: the data that cant be copied]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### First of all some thoughts to improve your coding style

1. You should avoid using `Selection`, `Select` and `Activate` because this is a bad practice and slows down your code a lot. You can do all actions without using them. In most cases you should never use them (there are a very little number of special cases).
2. Don't use eg. `Range` or `Cells` without specifying a worksheet. Otherwise Excel tries to guess which worksheet you mean and it will probably fail doing this. Guessing is not knowing, therefore **always** tell Excel which worksheet you mean like `Worksheets(1).Range` or `Worksheets("SheetName").Range`.
3. Use descriptive variable names. Names like `wbk` and `wbk1` are not very descriptive and later you don't know what `wbk1` was and mess things up. Instead use something like `wbDestination` and `wbSource` everybody knows what that means now.
   Also it might be a good practice to declare the variables close to their first use, especially when code gets a bit longer.
4. Always use `Worksheets` instead of `Sheets` if possible. `Sheets` also contains charts not only workbooks but in most cases you just want the `Worksheets`. You say it doesn't matter? Well it does. `Sheets(1).Range` will throw an error if the first sheet is a chart. We can avoid that.

#### Now lets start tidy up …

Instead of activate, select 3 times and copy

```
wbk.Activate
Range("A2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
```

We can just copy without any ativate or select which is a lot faster and has the same effect:

```
With wbSource.Worksheets(1).Range("A2")
    'copy without select
    .Resize(.End(xlDown).Row - .Row + 1, .End(xlToRight).Column - .Column + 1).Copy
End With
```

---

When we close the source workbook

```
wbSource.Close SaveChanges:=False
```

we don't need to save the changes because we didn't change anything. This is more secure and a lot faster.

#### So we end up with

```
Option Explicit

Sub MergeDataFromWorkbooks()
    Dim wbDestination As Workbook
    Set wbDestination = ThisWorkbook

    Dim Path As String
    Path = "C:\Temp\" 'make sure it ends with \

    Dim Filename As String
    Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xlsx")

    Do While Len(Filename) > 0 'while file exists
        Dim wbSource As Workbook
        Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(Path & Filename)    

        With wbSource.Worksheets(1).Range("A2")
            'copy without select
            .Resize(.End(xlDown).Row - .Row + 1, .End(xlToRight).Column - .Column + 1).Copy
        End With

        Dim lRow As Double
        lRow = wbDestination.Worksheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'find next empty row

        wbDestination.Worksheets(1).Cells(lRow + 1, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll 'paste all

        wbSource.Close SaveChanges:=False 'we don't need to save changes we didn't change anything just copied
        Filename = Dir 'next file
    Loop

    MsgBox "All the files are copied and pasted in Book1."
End Sub
```

#### Alternative way to determine the last used cell (column and row) in the source file

This avoids errors when row 2 is the last used row.

```
With wbSource.Worksheets(1).Range("A2")
    .Resize(.Parent.Cells(.Parent.Rows.Count, .Column).End(xlUp).Row - .Row + 1, .Parent.Cells(.Row, .Parent.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column - .Column + 1).Copy
End With
```

Explanation:

```
.Parent.Cells(.Parent.Rows.Count, .Column).End(xlUp).Row
```

finds the last used row in column A by starting from the very last cell in Excel and going up (like pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>up</kbd>).

Comment: actually it havent solve the problem it still have the problem where I can copy worksheet with more than one row  cell value but can't copy worksheet with only one row of cell value

Comment: @wt1155  The error you described in your question should not occur unless there are any merged cells.

Comment: i think i wil provide a screenshot of my data

Comment: try `.Resize(.Parent.Cells(.Parent.Rows.Count, .Column).End(xlUp).Row - .Row + 1, .Parent.Cells(.Row, .Parent.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column - .Column + 1).Copy` instead.

Comment: OMG it works !!. Can i know what mistake is made so i can take precaution next time if im doing the same thing ?

Comment: The issue here was the first code theoretically did the same as: Select A2 and press Ctrl+Shift+Down. If you do this manually on that file it will select from A2 to A1048576 which is pretty much. But the new code does: Select A1048576 and press Ctrl+Up this way it only selects A2. This is just a better way to find the last used cell I think. (Same for the column)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why your code is thrown a `Copy Area and Paste area aren't the same size` error.  Unless there are merged cells.

Select and Active are generally used to show the user something.  You can and should not use them unless absolutely necessary.  I recommend watching: [Excel VBA Introduction Part 5 - Selecting Cells (Range, Cells, Activecell, End, Offset)](https://www.youtube.com//watch?v=c8reU-H1PKQ&index=5&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5)

```
Dim Source As Range
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Do While Len(Filename) > 0                        'IF NEXT FILE EXISTS THEN

    With Workbooks.Open(Path & Filename)
        Set Source = .Range(.Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp), .Cells(1, 
        .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
    End With

    Source.Copy Workbooks("Book1.xlsm").Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
    .Close False
    Filename = Dir
Loop
```